# different fonts add on to website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I would like to know how i can allow new fonts to change the text inside my draggable i can only change fonts using the "old" fonts (standard font) i would like to use "new fonts" like The Godfather, Chlorinar, Earwig Factory, exc how can i add these fonts to my website without making users to download them

```html
<select id="fs">
  <option value="Agency FB" style="font-family: 'Agency FB'">Agency FB</option>
  <option value="Algerian" style="font-family: 'Algerian'">Algerian</option>
  <option value="AR Berkley" style="font-family: 'AR Berkley'">AR Berkley</option>
  <option value="Earwig Factory" style="font-family: 'Earwig Factory'">Earwig Factory</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I add new fonts like earwig factory font into my web page

Comment: Look up `@font-face` in CSS

Comment: Maybe you refer to add external fonts to your page https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: I tried that but i didn't know how it worked and deleted it @font-face {
    font-family: Earwig Factory;
    src: url(font/Earwig Factory.ttf);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face { font-family: SF-UI-Display-Ultralight; src: url('fonts/SF-UI-Display-Ultralight.otf'); }
```

Above is an example of adding a font in CSS. Of course pointing to the actual font file.

```
font-family: SF-UI-Display-Ultralight;
```

Then you can just add that to your CSS and you should be good. Be aware you can't change the font of option tags. I think MAYBE Firefox supports it but most browsers don't.